# Create a validation rule that checks that Warranty picklist field is not blank, when status = Containment Acheived / Root Cause / Corrective Action

Tags: picklist, custom-field, status

```
AND (ISPICKVAL (Status, "Containment Achieved / Root Cause / 
                Corrective Action / Preventative Action / 
                Closed"),
OR (ISBLANK( Warrantyy__c ) ) 
)
```

Comment: Try using if-then formula. It'd be like - 
IF( 
AND( OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Containment Achieved'), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Root Cause'), 
.......other values
), ISBLANK( Warrantyy__c )), TRUE, FALSE)


So it checks if one of the statuses is true and the warranty is blank. In that case, it returns true which inturn block the flow.

Comment: The issue is in how you check the Status; you need an OR for each option, not using a string with slashes in it.

Answer (score 2):

You must test each status separately, and OR these together. If the status is one of the required values AND the warranty is blank there is a validation failure.

I have used `||` for OR and `&&` for AND so I get the operator as "infix" (between the operands) which I find easier to read than the `AND` and `OR` function notation:

```
(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Containment Achieved") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Status, "Root Cause") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Status, "Corrective Action") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Status, "Preventative Action") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed")) &&
ISBLANK(Warranty__c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you must perform separate checks for each item you want test for.

There are a few tricks that we can use though. `CONTAINS()` can be used to check if a single value matches any number of target values, and `CASE()` can help reduce the amount of typing.

### Using `CONTAINS()`

`CONTAINS(haystack, needle)` works when you have a single value you're trying to find (the "needle"). The "haystack" would be the potential values you want to look for, and each needs to be separated with a delimiter (i.e. something that doesn't appear in the strings you're trying to use). The Pipe, `|` is a standard choice for the delimiter

```
AND(
    CONTAINS(
        'Containment Achieved|Root Cause|Corrective Action|Preventative Action|Closed`, 
        TEXT(Status)
    ),
    /* and then the isblank for the warranty */
)
```

The main scenario where this won't work is when the needle contains two (or more) values in the haystack. If your haystack is `'Red|Green|Blue'`, a needle of `'Red Green'` won't work.

### Using `CASE()`

If you want to use `CASE()`, then we need to work around the fact that it can't return a boolean. The normal workaround for that is to assign `1` as the result for the things we're looking for, default to 0, and then compare against `1`.

```
AND(
    CASE(Status,
        'Containment Achieved', 1,
        'Root Cause', 1,
        'Corrective Action', 1,
        'Preventative Action', 1,
        'Closed', 1,
        0
    ) = 1,
    /* and then the isblank for the warranty */
)
```

`CASE()` is one of the few things that can work with picklists directly.

Comment: We use the CASE approach in some scenarios, though it's less directly obvious which is why I didn't suggest it here... I would never use the CONTAINS approach since you may find you have inadvertent false matches. Imagine a Status of "Contain" (as in "keep under control") this would inappropriately be found to be contained in the list of status names, since it is a substring of "Containment Achieved".